# Spring-boot Error starting ApplicationContext and Application startup failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I recently start to develop a web application with spring-boot, for recommendation for StackOverflow dataset but i am gettig errors.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>io.spring.recommendation-engine</groupId>
        <artifactId>recommendation_engine</artifactId>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>recommendation_engine</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
        <modules>
            <module>database-import</module>
            <module>recommender-job</module>
            <module>spark-import-job</module>
            <module>spark-recommender-job</module>
            <module>jdbchdfspartitioned</module>
            <module>spring-overflow-spring</module>
        </modules>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
                <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </project>
```

**Application.java**

```
package io.spring.springoverflow;

import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.jdbc.MySQLBooleanPrefJDBCDataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.AllSimilarItemsCandidateItemsStrategy;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericItemBasedRecommender;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.similarity.jdbc.MySQLJDBCInMemoryItemSimilarity;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.ItemBasedRecommender;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.similarity.ItemSimilarity;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {


    @Bean
    ItemBasedRecommender recommender(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        DataModel dataModel = new MySQLBooleanPrefJDBCDataModel(dataSource);
        ItemSimilarity similarity = new MySQLJDBCInMemoryItemSimilarity(dataSource);
        AllSimilarItemsCandidateItemsStrategy candidateItemsStrategy =
                new AllSimilarItemsCandidateItemsStrategy(similarity);
        return new GenericItemBasedRecommender(dataModel, similarity, candidateItemsStrategy, candidateItemsStrategy);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

but when I try run the application with `java -jar appname` i get the error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


2017-03-28 10:49:50.449 ERROR 2866 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.ItemBasedRecommender io.spring.springoverflow.controller.PostController.recommender; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'recommender' defined in class io.spring.springoverflow.Application: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.ItemBasedRecommender io.spring.springoverflow.Application.recommender(javax.sql.DataSource) throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at io.spring.springoverflow.Application.main(Application.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.ItemBasedRecommender io.spring.springoverflow.controller.PostController.recommender; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'recommender' defined in class io.spring.springoverflow.Application: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.ItemBasedRecommender io.spring.springoverflow.Application.recommender(javax.sql.DataSource) throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not autowire field in spring. why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954461/could-not-autowire-field-in-spring-why)

Comment: Have you actually read the stack trace? `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions` seems pretty clear to me, indicates you are missing a dependency.

Comment: Thanks. I got a solution.

Comment: @MPankajArun what solution you got?

Comment: @TejKiran I was missing some dependencies. So I have made available those.